# How did bitlocker instantly encrypt my drive and why doesn't it ask for password to boot the PC?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

I've got a decently recent Lenovo laptop from my workplace with most of the current acronyms on it - like TPM, UEFI and NVME. It also has Windows 11.

The company is not large and only recently have we started to more seriously crack down on security. One new measure is to require to have Bitlocker enabled on all laptops. Fair enough. I've never done this before, so today I decided to do it thinking that it would take a while to encrypt my SSD. It's not terribly large - only 256GB - but it's something like 75% full and I'd expect that encrypting it would take maybe an hour or so.

Great was my surprise that it was done instantly upon clicking "Enable Bitlocker". Even running `manage-bde -status` command shows that the drive is 100% encrypted. Huh?

In addition, the system booted up just fine without asking any passwords for booting (well, until it got to the login screen). This I suspect might be thanks to UEFI and TPM - I can see the encryption keys being securely stored there. A confirmation would be nice though.

But how did it encrypt the drive so quickly? Or was the drive already encrypted all along, and it just pretended that Bitlocker was off?

Comment: Bitllocker often comes installed (better to install it before the OS).  Look in Control Panel  Very likely already ON.

Comment: https://www.n-able.com/blog/are-you-sure-your-devices-are-fully-encrypted-with-bitlocker

Comment: “how did it encrypt the drive so quickly?” - BitLocker was enabled and the encryption process was performed in the background. I wouldn’t expect 256GB drive to take more than hour to encrypt.

Comment: @John - No, it was off before and I turned it on.  At least that's what Windows showed me.

Comment: @Ramhound - in that case I would expect `manage-bde -status` to show that the drive is being encrypted - but it showed it as being 100% done already. The disk activity is also 0%.

Comment: I am confused. Typically BitLocker would be enabled through a group policy in an enterprise setting. This means BitLocker would be enabled and you wouldn’t necessarily be aware when it was enabled.

Comment: You (OP) said new(ish) computer. Bitlocker comes installed and running in a lot of cases on new(ish) computers - that is what I see here.

Comment: @Ramhound - We're not very "enterprisey" here. We don't have a Windows domain, for instance, hence no group policies. As I said, the company isn't large. I'm sure we'll get there eventually. :)

Comment: @John - Maybe, but Windows said it was disabled before I clicked "Enable" on it. I didn't check `manage-bde -status` before I enabled it though - maybe it was secretly enabled already.

Comment: So how it the use of BitLocker enforced? Who enabled  BitLocker protection?

Comment: @Ramhound I did. Because they asked me to. :) It's not literally enforced yet. I suppose I should add that I'm a software developer and I'm entrusted with my PC to the fullest. I have local administrator access. For the less technical users there's someone who helps them to enable Bitlocker. For me they just asked me to do it myself.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Please read the comments above. There was no group policy, because the computer was never a part of a domain.